Docker still using cache after a prune - how to delete the cache?
I want to ensure everything's re-done, but the system pruning isn't helping - how do I make sure the cache is clear?
$ docker system prune --all --volumes --force
Total reclaimed space: 0B
$ docker builder prune --all --force
Total:  0B
$ docker build # args...
...
 => CACHED [root 2/4] WORKDIR /root                                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [root 3/4] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --yes     bear     clang     clang-format     clang-tidy     cmake>=3  0.0s
...


Please include the output of docker builder du after the prune, and provide a [mcve].

This command delete only images that do not used anywhere. So you can try to remove all running and stopped containers
docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)
And run prune system again.
docker system prune --all
It could help you to clear old images
Other solution you can build container without using cache at all
docker build --no-cache .
